# I'm using a CNAME to send www. traffic to domain without www. Will this hurt my SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, no-www

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the “canonical name” in DNS make any difference to search engines?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/does-the-canonical-name-in-dns-make-any-difference-to-search-engines)

Mu understanding is that CNAME should be used for subdomains and www is just another subdomain. Of course I could do a 301 redirect but it seems odd to do that when I've got it working now and I'm an apache noob so I rather wouldn't mess with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set example.com and www.example.com to the same IP address (www is a CNAME of @) then it depends how you have it configured on the server. You should NEVER have a website load for both the naked domain AND the www subdomain. I would personally pick which you want to run the site on: www or naked domain. If you want to run it on www, go to http://wwwizer.com and then copy the IP (174.129.25.170) and set it as the A-record for the naked domain, then set your www-subdomain to the IP of YOUR server. This pops a 301 redirect for anyone accessing your naked domain. If you want to REMOVE the www, and make all users use the naked domain, you will need to do some server-side config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can pop that into a .htaccess or into the httpd.conf or wherever your Apache config files are. (Be sure to restart Apache if you change anything).

For SEO purposes, see here: http://www.toxzen.co.za/tutorials/item/50-to-www-or-not-to-www-that-is-an-seo-question

It's essential to use a 301 redirect either to add or remove the www. You have to choose one, and must stick with it. `"It doesn't matter which you choose but you should pick one and be consistent ... So whichever you choose for aesthetic reasons should be consistently used for SEO reasons"`